# JS-based hidden image breaks body width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I use a Zoom JavaScript for zoom my images when I click on it.
This JavaScript creates a hidden copy of my image with bigger dimensions.

Problem is, when I load my page, the body takes a height and width according to the hidden image.

[image: My problem]

You can see at the right of the screen the menu doesn't fit with the width of the screen (the hidden image is not displayed).
Is there a solution when I load the page, the size of the body does not take into account the hidden image?

```js
// To achieve this effect we're creating a copy of the image and scaling it up. Next we'll pull the x and y coordinates of the mouse on the original image. Then we translate the big image so that the points we are looking at match up. Finally we create a mask to display the piece of the image that we're interested in.

let settings = {
  'magnification': 3,
  'maskSize': 200
}

// Once our images have loaded let's create the zoom
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // find all the images
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('.image-zoom-available');
  // querySelectorAll produces an array of images that we pull out one by one and create a Zoombini for
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (image) => {
    new Zoombini(image);
  });
});

// A Zoombini (or whatever you want to call it), is a class that takes an image input and adds the zoomable functionality to it. Let's take a look inside at what it does.
class Zoombini {
  // When we create a new Zoombini we run this function; it's called the constructor and you can see it taking our image in from above
  constructor(targetImage) {
    // We don't want the Zoombini to forget about it's image, so let's save that info
    this.image = targetImage;
    // The Zoombini isActive after it has opened up 
    this.isActive = false;
    // But as it hasn't been used yet it's maskSize will be 0
    this.maskSize = 0;
    // And we have to start it's coordinates somewhere, they may as well be (0,0)
    this.mousex = this.mousey = 0;

    // Now we're set up let's build the necessary compoonents
    // First let's clone our original image, I'm going to call it imageZoom and save it our Zoombini
    this.imageZoom = this.image.cloneNode();
    // And pop it next to the image target
    this.image.parentNode.insertBefore(this.imageZoom, this.image);
    // Make the zoom image that we'll crop float above it's original sibling
    this.imageZoom.style.zIndex = 1;
    // We don't want to be able to touch it though, we want to reach whats underneat
    this.imageZoom.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    // And so we can translate it let's make it absolute
    this.imageZoom.style.position = "absolute";

    // Now let's scale up our enlarged image and add an event listener so that it resizes whenever the size of the window changes
    this.resizeImageZoom();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeImageZoom.bind(this), false);

    // Now that we're finishing the constructor we need to addeventlisteners so we can interact with it
    // This function is just below, but still exists within our Zoombini
    this.UI();
    // Finally we'll apply an initial mask at default settings to hide this image
    this.drawMask();
  }

  // resizeImageZoom resizes the enlarged image
  resizeImageZoom() {
    // So let's scale up this version
    this.imageZoom.style.width = this.image.getBoundingClientRect().width * settings.magnification + 'px';
    this.imageZoom.style.height = "unset"
  }

  // This could be inside the constructor but it's nicer on it's own I think
  UI() {
    this.image.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      // When we move our mouse the x and y coordinates from the event
      // We subtract the left and top coordinates so that we get the (x,y) coordinates of the actualy image, where (0,0) would be the top left
      this.mousex = event.clientX - this.image.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      this.mousey = event.clientY - this.image.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      // if we're not active then don't display anything
      if (!this.isActive) return;
      // The drawMask() function below displays our the portion of the image that we're interested in
      this.drawMask();
    });

    // When they mousedown we open up our mask
    this.image.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      // But it can be opening or closing, so let's pass in that information
      this.isExpanding = true;
      // To do that we start the maskSizer function, which calls itself until it reaches full size
      this.maskSizer();
      // And hide our cursor (we know where it is)
      this.image.classList.add('is-active');
    });
    // if the mouse is released, close the mask
    this.image.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      // if it's not expanding, it's closing
      this.isExpanding = false;
      // if the mask has already expanded we'll need to start another maskSizer to shrink it. We don't run the maskSizer unless the mask is changing
      if (this.isActive) this.maskSizer();
    });
    // same as above, caused by us moving out of the zoom area
    this.image.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      this.isExpanding = false;
      if (this.isActive) this.maskSizer();
    });
  }

  // The drawmask function shows us the piece of the image that we are hovering over
  drawMask() {
    // Let's use getBoundingClientRect to get the location of our images
    let image = this.image.getBoundingClientRect();
    let imageZoom = this.imageZoom.getBoundingClientRect();
    // We'll start by getting the (x,y) of our big image that matches the piece we're mousing over (which we stored from our event listener as this.mousex and this.mousey). This is a clunky bit of code to help the zooms work in a variety of situations.
    let prop_x = this.mousex / image.width * imageZoom.width * (1 - 1 / settings.magnification) - image.x - window.scrollX;
    let prop_y = this.mousey / image.height * imageZoom.height * (1 - 1 / settings.magnification) - image.y - window.scrollY;
    // Shift the large image by that amount
    this.imageZoom.style.left = -prop_x + "px";
    this.imageZoom.style.top = -prop_y + "px";

    // Now we need to create our mask
    // First let's get the coordinates of the point we're hovering over
    let x = this.mousex * settings.magnification;
    let y = this.mousey * settings.magnification;
    // And create and apply our clip
    let clippy = "circle(" + this.maskSize + "px at " + x + "px " + y + "px)";
    this.imageZoom.style.clipPath = clippy;
    this.imageZoom.style.webkitClipPath = clippy;
  }

  // We'll use the maskSizer to either expand or shrink the size of our mask
  maskSizer() {
    // We're in maskSizer so we're changing the size of our mask. Let's make the mask radius larger if the Zoombini is expanding, or shrink it if it's closing. The numbers below might need to be adjusted. It closes faster than it opens
    this.maskSize = this.isExpanding ? this.maskSize + 35 : this.maskSize - 40;
    // It has the form of: condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false
    // Think of the ? as "then" and : as "else"

    // if we've reaached max size, don't make it any larger
    if (this.maskSize >= settings.maskSize) {
      this.maskSize = settings.maskSize;
      // we'll no longer need to change the maskSize so we'll just set this.isActive to true and let our mousemove do the drawing
      this.isActive = true;
    } else if (this.maskSize < 0) {
      // Our mask is closed
      this.maskSize = 0;
      this.isActive = false;
      this.image.classList.remove('is-active');
    } else {
      // Or else we haven't reached a size that we want to keep yet. So let's loop it on the next available frame
      // We bind(this) here because so that the function remains in context
      requestAnimationFrame(this.maskSizer.bind(this));
    }
    // After we have the appropriate size, draw the mask
    this.drawMask();
  }
}

function zoom(e) {
  var zoomer = e.currentTarget;
  e.offsetX ? offsetX = e.offsetX : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  e.offsetY ? offsetY = e.offsetY : offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX
  x = offsetX / zoomer.offsetWidth * 100
  y = offsetY / zoomer.offsetHeight * 100
  zoomer.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
}
```

```css
//My image generated after page load
.image-zoom-available {
    height: unset;
    border-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 834.688px;
    left: 526.646px;
    top: 231.729px;
    clip-path: circle(0px at 439.062px 987.812px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12  col-xl-3 col-lg-5 justify-content-center ">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <img class="image-zoom-available" style="height:75%; border-radius: 30px" src='{{ asset(' /radio/ ') }}{{examen.idpatient.id}}_examen_{{examen.id}}_radio.png' id="image_radio" draggable="false" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add

```
this.imageZoom.style.display = "none";
```

on the event : mouseup and

```
this.imageZoom.style.display = "block";
```

on mousedown event. And it's fix thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following property in your hidden image css :

```
display: none
```

A non visible element still take space in the web page. Cf: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Remove or override the `display: none` property when you want to display the image.

Comment: If I add display: none, when I click on my image "the zoom" doesn't appear. I edited the CSS of image-zoom-available class

Comment: You need to set it to `display:none` when it's hidden, and `display:block` (or inline, or something else that's visible) when it's not supposed to be hidden.

Comment: I edited my answer. But I'm not sure you are using the right tool for this feature, a simple image viewer library with a zoom feature may already exists.